# How to get the (literally) entered Discount Code?

Tags: magento2, discount, plugin

I'm using Magento 2 and I've created a Plugin based on

```
Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface
```

My plugin is working fine, I can get value from the log. But, my problem is the following: I want to get the actually entered discount code (in the Apply Discount Code field during checkout). But, in my plugin it keeps returning 25. (I've entered a fake code 12345).

```
public function beforeSet($cartId, $couponCode) {
  $log = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."CouponManagement.log", "a");
  fwrite($log, date("d-m-Y H:i's")." beforeSet: ".$couponCode."\r\n");
  fclose($log);
}
```

No matter what I do, it keeps returning/writing: *timestamp* beforeSet: 25

What I basically want is to use the entered code to call an external API to return an existing giftcard value which I can than use to *insert* (and use) as a new Discount Code into Magento.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Defining a Plugin: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#defining-a-plugin

> The first argument for the before, after, and around methods is an
>   object that provides access to all public methods of the observed
>   method’s class.

In your case, you forgot to add the first argument: `\Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface $subject`

Your DI xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="setCouponData"
                type="Vendor\Coupon\Model\Plugin\SetCouponData"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Your Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Coupon\Model\Plugin;

class SetCouponData
{
    public function beforeSet(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface $subject,
        $cartId,
        $couponCode
    ) {
      // Your code here
    }
}
```

Now, your coupon code is the third argument.